# Missing right parenthesis error while creating a table with SQL code generated in Vertabelo

Tags: oracle

I want to create a Database for my school project. Some tables were created without an error, but when I wanted to create a more complex table, I had this error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

The code is following (the names of the table and attributes are in Romanian):

```
CREATE TABLE Curse (
id_cursa int  NOT NULL,
id_tura int  NULL,
moment_inceput_cursa timestamp  NULL,
moment_sfarsit_cursa timestamp  NULL,
adresa_initiala text  NULL,
GPS_punct_start text  NULL,
adresa_destinatie text  NULL,
destinatie_GPS text  NULL,
stare_cursa char NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
modalitate_plata int  NULL,
pret decimal  NULL,
CONSTRAINT Curse_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_cursa)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few objections:

- `TEXT` datatype is invalid; I used `VARCHAR2(100)`; could be larger, or `CLOB`
- correct order is `DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL` (not `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`)
- Although it is not *an error*, you don't have to specify that `NULL` values are allowed

---

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE curse(
  2    id_cursa               INT NOT NULL,
  3    id_tura                INT NULL,
  4    moment_inceput_cursa   TIMESTAMP NULL,
  5    moment_sfarsit_cursa   TIMESTAMP NULL,
  6    adresa_initiala        VARCHAR2(100)NULL,
  7    gps_punct_start        VARCHAR2(100)NULL,
  8    adresa_destinatie      VARCHAR2(100)NULL,
  9    destinatie_gps         VARCHAR2(100)NULL,
 10    stare_cursa            CHAR DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 11    modalitate_plata       INT NULL,
 12    pret                   DECIMAL,
 13    CONSTRAINT curse_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_cursa)
 14  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: CHAR without precision is okay, it defaults to `char(1)`. `decimal` is fine as a subtype of `number` (like `int`).

Comment: So true; thank you, @APC. I fixed that code, as well as comments.

Answer (score 1):

The actual fault is the DEFAULT clause comes before the NOT NULL clause. So this the correct syntax:

```
stare_cursa char DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

Beyond that you need to change the `text` datatype to something like `varchar2(1000)` or whatever length you need.